# Mongodb / node.js installation

Tags: node.js, macos, mongodb, terminal

I am trying to use node.js and mongodb on a mac. I downloaded both and when installing mongodb, I was told it should be at the following path

/usr/local/bin/npm

However in terminal, I could not find mongodb at all, except in Downloads. so I used the sudo mv command to move mongodb from downloads to the above path. This would not work, but it would let me move mongodb to the following path.

/usr/local/bin

However when I tried to run mongod, I get an error message.

Does anyone know why this might be? I installed node and mongodb into node_modules. I am new to node.js and mongodb, so apologies if I have made some very basic error.

Cheers

Comment: Clean up (un-do) what you have done and follow these instructions: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-mac - current best practice.

Comment: I got it working, thank you.